# How to make a consistent outline around vertices

Tags: vertices

I am trying to make an edge around this vertices outline by extruding it but it looks bad.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: sorry it's not clear what part you're trying to do and what is your problem, can you explain more in detail?